# Connection Refused for my cdatabase

Tags: linux, security, mysql

```
nc 144.143.254.56 3306
(UNKNOWN) [144.143.254.56] 3306 (mysql) : Connection refused
```

However...when I type "localhost", it works!

```
nc localhost 3306
@5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2%YRmN"Xvl,9uf|^@eZvadS
```

Why? How do I enable it so that I can connect through an IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/1134) should help.